# Select records from SAP MDG?

Tags: abap, master-data-management

I am new to SAP-MDG and I have added few customers using the standard SAP screens, I am interested in knowing if we can directly connect to MDG tables using Hana Studio.

Tables like **MARA or KNA1**, can I directly fire select queries on these tables?

---

> select * from KNA1 fetch first 3 rows only;

---

something like this?

Thank you,

Divyesh Kalbhor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this to store any three records from KNA1 into an internal table:

```
DATA: lt_KNA1 LIKE TABLE OF KNA1.

select * from KNA1 INTO lt_KNA1 up to 3 rows.
```

Comment: `OCCURS` and `WITH HEADER LINE` are deprecated statements, and shouldn't be used longer.

Comment: So where do I fire this query? Like for DB2 we have TOAD or AQT, do we have some tool for MDG tables?

Comment: @Suncatcher, true, that comes from my time as ABAP programmer, changed.

Comment: @DivyeshKalbhor, you can run this query in any ABAP-program, but also you can run queries in native SQL [like this](http://www.sap-perf.ca/execute-sql-statement-directly-in-sap/).

Comment: @Suncatcher : Did that! It worked. Thank you for your help.